# GlassFish in my Local Network - Access the apps From another pc

Tags: java, glassfish, lan

I need help with javaEE and Glassfish Server.  I have my app with the glassfish, running, and I want show it in my local network. if I write "localhost:8080/myApp" using a browser in the computer where my app is installed, everything is ok,  but when I am trying to access to it from another pc, writing "192.168.1.4:8080/myApp", I can't... why? using Tomcat, I haven't problem. (192.168.1.4 is the address of the computer with the app)

anyway, please, can you help me? how can I get the GlassFish visible (myapp visible) for the other computers in the LAN?

pd: please forgive my bad english :D

Thank You!!

Comment: what is the error message in browser ?

Comment: can you ping the server?

Comment: thank for response, there is not any message, simply "IE explorer cannot show the web page" :(

Comment: yes i can ping the server.